# Сборка ядра Debian

Tags: debian, kernel

Требуется по заданию обновить ядро Debian, собрав его из исходников не ванильного ядра. Есть такой пакет: https://packages.debian.org/jessie-updates/linux-source-3.16, я так понял, что это и есть исходники ядра debian. Устанавливал его с помощью dpkg. Теперь он отображается при вызове aptitude versions linux-source-3.16 вместе с 3.16.7-ckt11-1 и 3.16.7-ckt11-1+deb8u3. Но никаких исходников для сборки не нахожу. Что я делаю не так, и как правильно?

Comment: /usr/src/linux отсутствует?

Comment: https://wiki.debian.org/BuildADebianKernelPackage

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Появился архив с исходниками, спасибо.